# Broken images if not using www in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have a react app that I've been working on for a while. I added a new page today that has a few images on it that worked perfectly locally. I built and uploaded the package to the server and at first it seemed everything was fine. However, I followed a different link to the page and discovered that the images were not being displayed. The only difference between the two links are one is using the www, the other isn't.

My image is being created like this (same as all of the other images on my site)

```
<img style={{ height: 75, width: 75 }} src={"/images/images.jpg"} />
```

I checked the Network in Chrome Dev Tools and it's showing a 200 for all 4 images (for both links). If I do a right mouse click over the broken image icon and choose open in a new window, I get the same results (works with www, doesn't without).

I don't know if this will make a difference, but here's my .htaccess rewrite's:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where are your images?

Comment: They're all in a folder off the root called images.

Comment: can you post your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

*They're all in a folder off the root called images*

**I think webpack ignored your images, and your image are not added in bundle.**

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files),

I suggest you to keep your images in `src` folder.

Create a folder `images` in `src` folder and add your images to it.

```
--root (folder)
  --public (folder)
  --src (folder)
    --images (folder)
      --images.jpg (image file)
    --components (folder)
      --App.js (file)
    --index.js (file)
```

Now you can access your image in `App.js` file like,

```
import image from '../images/images.jpg';     //You should add correct path to your image from your currect component

<img style={{ height: 75, width: 75 }} src={image} />
```

**This ensures that when the project is built, Webpack will correctly move the images into the build folder, and provide us with correct paths.**

**Note:** You can add this to your `.htaccess` file,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
```

Comment: I read the link you included, and I've seen that before. The folder structure that I have is similar, except the images folder is under the public folder. According to the documentation, that folder will be copied to the root folder and allow direct access, which I did.
As a test, I copied the images folder to src and changed one img tag. All of them started working. So, I changed it back, and they're all still working.
I'm thinking a temporary server issue???
Is there a benefit to including the images within the build???

Comment: External assets should be in public folder or src folder only to include them in build so that server can serve them.

Comment: If the assets are not included in build then server can not serve.